# What part of speech is "that"?

Tags: parts-of-speech

> The fact is that it makes no practical difference.

What part of speech is "that" ?

Comment: Did you look it up in a dictionary? What did it say?

Comment: *That* links the subordinate clause "it makes no practical difference" to the main clause "The fact is...." So some grammars call *that* a subordinating conjunction.

Comment: Dictionaries aren't very helpful when it comes to parts of speech. "That" is a subordinator.

Comment: I agree with user 178049: its part of speech is **subordinator**. See the second definition here: [link](https://simple.wiktionary.org/wiki/that).